# How to count the number of values based on another column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The question title might be too implicit. 
Let's say we have a spark data frame:

```
user_ID         phone_number
--------------------------------
A                 1234567
B                 1234567
C                 8888888
D                 9999999
E                 1234567
F                 8888888
G                 1234567
```

And we need to count, for each user_ID, how many user_ID's share the same phone_number with it. For table listed before, the desired result should be:

```
user_ID         count_of_userID_who_share_the_same_phone_number
----------------------------------------------------------------
A                 4
B                 4
C                 2
D                 1
E                 4
F                 2
G                 4
```

It can be achieved by writing self-join queries in `spark.sql(query)`, but the the performance is quite heart-breaking. 
Any suggestion how I can get a much faster implementation? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Spark's `Window` function should perform significantly better than `self-join`:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("A", "1234567"),
  ("B", "1234567"),
  ("C", "8888888"),
  ("D", "9999999"),
  ("E", "1234567"),
  ("F", "8888888"),
  ("G", "1234567")
).toDF(
    "user_id", "phone_number"
)

// Add phone number count via window function
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df2 = df.withColumn("count", count("user_id").over(
  Window.partitionBy("phone_number")
)).orderBy("user_id")

df2.show
+-------+------------+-----+
|user_id|phone_number|count|
+-------+------------+-----+
|      A|     1234567|    4|
|      B|     1234567|    4|
|      C|     8888888|    2|
|      D|     9999999|    1|
|      E|     1234567|    4|
|      F|     8888888|    2|
|      G|     1234567|    4|
+-------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Just tried, much much faster than simple spark.sql queries! thx

Comment: Glad that it helps.